# How to create customize Html Editor in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have requirement to create Customize Ext JS HTML Editor. I am facing problem in creating it.

Comment: What do you mean by "customize"?

Comment: I mean that when I use Extjs htmleditor I am facing problem it's look and feel is not good .It toolbar is not looking attractive how can i customize it.

Comment: So you just want to use CSS to style the toolbar or are you wanting to use `Ext.define` to create a subclass to add more functionality to suit your needs?

Comment: Can u provide me any source Code so i can make it presentable

Comment: I think I have to create the subclass

Comment: I cannot since you aren't providing any real information to do anything yet. Please tell me more about what you want, I'd recommend editing your original question above.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the toolbar, because it isn't looking attractive, [have a look at this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g2v).

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I found some spare time [for this example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g32).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing any information at all there are several solutions:

- You can use CSS to style your HTML editor
- You can use another editor, like TinyMCE to add extra functionality
- You can have a look at the documentation on how to alter functionality of the current editor any maybe even create a subclass of it.

Hope this helps a bit.